# floating DIV all over others

Tags: jquery, css, html, timeline

Well it's more like question of HOW to call it to find it :) Point of creating newsline with short story DIVs into columns like old facebook timeline, but over two lines, most of links i found are like above describes fb timeline. [link01](http://htun.me/labs/timeline.php) or [link02](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/01/facebook-timeline-design-using-jquery.html)
But i'm more interested of creating something like: 
[image: example]

Checked at stackoverflow, lot's of info, but we're getting back to above described fb two columns. Anyone had expirience or ideas of that kind of structure?

Comment: [That article](http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/) looks interessting.

Comment: Thanks! Already checkin' what's inside of it :)))

Answer (score 5):

There are two jQuery plugins that immediately come to mind reading your question.

- [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) - A dynamic layout plugin for jQuery. The flip-side of CSS floats.
- [Wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) - Javascript to create a waterfall grid layout.

Both of these plugins will be able to assist you in obtaining the layout/structure you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks mate ;) exactly what i've been lookin' 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge that is called a *mozaic* layout and you can achieve a similar effec using **[masonry js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check out [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/). You can split your content up to 16 columns. It's really the most flexible solution that's done entirely in CSS. You'll have to put more work into this one since it's only a "foundation" and not a plugin.